# Amazon Redshift: Finding the size of a database without superuser visibility

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've found many articles detailing how to use `stv_tbl_perm`, `stv_blocklist`, and `svv_table_info` in a query to access the size of a Redshift database. However, these tables are only visible to superusers, and I'm attempting to access the size of a database as a user. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there more than one database on the cluster?  Does the database span S3 storage?

Comment: @BillWeiner There is only one database in the cluster, and it doesn't use S3.

Comment: One way to approximate the database size would be to look at the cluster disk usage metrics on the console.